# Why Is It That My Object Gets Added 6 Times?

Tags: swift, xcode, uitableview

I'm Trying to transfer my object from hockeyDetailVC to FavouritesVC using segue and a button from a tableView to another tableView.

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if segue.identifier == "r" {
    let destinationController = segue.destination as! FavouritesVC
    destinationController.currentFav = item!
}
}
```

but the issue is it transfers my object 6 times and I am not sure why it does that, it should only be once.

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
favArr.append(currentFav!)
print("this is how many players there are: \(favArr.count)") //At the end of execution gives me 6 players.
return favArr.count
}



var item: CurrentPlayers?          //This is what I want to transfer in my hockeyDetailVC

var currentFav: CurrentPlayers?    //This is the variable I set my transfer in FavouritesVC

class CurrentPlayers {
var photoUrl: String
var position: String
var team: String
var yahooName: String
var birthCity: String
var birthState: String
var status: String
var catches: String
var shoots: String
var jerseyNumber: Int
var largePhoto: String

init(photoUrl: String, position: String, team: String, yahooName: String, birthCity: String, status: String, catches: String, shoots: String, birthState: String, jerseyNumber: Int, largePhoto: String) {
    
    self.yahooName = yahooName
    self.photoUrl = photoUrl
    self.position = position
    self.team = team
    self.birthCity = birthCity
    self.status = status
    self.catches = catches
    self.shoots = shoots
    self.birthState = birthState
    self.jerseyNumber = jerseyNumber
    self.largePhoto = largePhoto

}
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`numberOfRowsInSection` must return the number of items in the given section, nothing else.

Remove

```
favArr.append(currentFav!)
```

from the method and put it into `viewDidLoad`